# Code First ASP.Net membership not synced with WSAT

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-membership, wsat

I used the WSAT to configure security, but the users I create with it are not being flowed through to the ASP.Net Membership that comes with the stock MVC template (they cannot log in to the site). Conversely, the users that I am registering via the MVC registration screen are not showing up in the WSAT Manage Users form.

I would like to create a few roles, but I am unsure how I put the users created with the MVC registration screen into the roles created with the WSAT since those two pieces don't appear to be communicating.

Answer (score 0):

In case this helps someone else: If you're going Code-First, ensure your connection string is named after your custom DbContext class.

```
public class MyCoolContext : DbContext{}
```

Change your connection string name from DefaultConnection to:

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="MyCoolContext" .... />
```

Ensure that InitializeSimpleMembershipAttribute under ~/Filters has this line:

```
WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("MyCoolContext", "UserProfile", "UserId", "UserName", autoCreateTables: true);
```

That will ensure your membership and EF schemas are rolled into a single db.